# fixing the layout with bootstrap flask

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>GucciGang Website</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.css') }}">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a class="brand" href="/">Real Python (for the web!)</a>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/">222</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                {% block content%}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

With the template.html above with Bootstrap, I expected my page to look like

[image]

but it actually looks like

[image]

Which part of my code is wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add navbar-nav class to your unordered list tag

<`ul class="nav navbar-nav">`

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp